# Need help Modifying how data is displayed via javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter-2

I have the code below and I need a little help in modifying the code output.

The code below is for a Codeigniter chat application where the user enters their message in the text box (#text) and the message is output, the message is saved in a MySQL database via PHP and then output to the textbox (#received).

I would like to modify the code to include the message sender and also show the messages with differentiation between the sender and recipient like google chat or Text message threads. The data output is via javascript and I am still a novice in the language.

This is the current chat thread output. [Current Chat Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20o5C.png). For the full CodeIgniter project code, [Click this link](https://github.com/Runnable/Chat-Example-App-for-Codeigniter-API-on-PHP). Any help or pointers will be appreciated.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var time = 0;

    var updateTime = function(cb) {
        $.getJSON("index.php/chat/time", function(data) {
            cb(~~data);
        });
    };

    var sendChat = function(message, cb) {
        $.getJSON("index.php/chat/insert_chat?message=" + message, function(data) {
            cb();
        });
    }

    var addDataToReceived = function(arrayOfData) {
        arrayOfData.forEach(function(data) {
            $("#received").val($("#received").val() + "\n" + data[0]);
        });
    }

    var getNewChats = function() {
        $.getJSON("index.php/chat/get_chats?time=" + time, function(data) {
            addDataToReceived(data);
            // reset scroll height
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#received').scrollTop($('#received')[0].scrollHeight);
            }, 0);
            time = data[data.length - 1][3];
        });
    }

    // using JQUERY's ready method to know when all dom elements are rendered
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // set an on click on the button
        $("form").submit(function(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            var data = $("#text").val();
            $("#text").val('');
            // get the time if clicked via a ajax get query
            sendChat(data, function() {
                alert("dane");
            });
        });
        setInterval(function() {
            getNewChats(0);
        }, 1500);
    });
</script>
<textarea id="received" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
<form>
    <input id="text" type="text" name="user">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the link it looks like it is impossible to differentiate messages by sender. Your application simply doesn't know who has sent a message.

So, first of all, you have to add a field in DB to store information about a sender. Most likely you'll have to implement some sort of authentication in the application. After that you'll be able to make differentiation on the client side.

On the client side you have to change the #received textbox to a div or some other block element. Doing this you'll be able to apply CSS styles to individual messages. Than you will need to change your `addDataToReceived` function in this way:

```
var addDataToReceived = function (arrayOfData) {
  arrayOfData.forEach(function (data) {
    var message = $('<div>');
    message.html(data[0]);

    if (data[2] === username) {
        // data[2] is a new element, it points to an author of the message
        //
        // username indentificates a current user
        // you'll save it to a variable after authentication somehow
        message.addClass('self-message');
    } else {
        message.addClass('other-message');
    }

    $("#received").append(message);
  });
}
```

It highly depends on a concrete realization, but all in all something like that.

Comment: I believe the php code for differentiating the sender and recipient will not be complicated for me. My main issue is with the JavaScript code for displaying the data as the whole conversation is displayed in a single textarea field and this makes it impossible to style the individual messages from by wrapping each message with a div tag. I tried replacing the textarea with a div with the id received but there was no data displayed.